# class wildcards in CSS Parse Error 'div.*{'

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

I noticed that I have a lot of repeated code in my divs and that some people had:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

That effects all elements including headings and paragraphs so I tried:

```
div.* {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Which is not working right and is showing up as a Parse Error in the w3c validator.

What is the correct wildcard for a class?

Comment: Why do you need a wildcard for classes? just omit the .* and the rule will apply to all div elements.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking, but I took a stab in the dark anyway just in case I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to match any `div` element that has a class, whatever that class may be?

If so, use an attribute selector:

```
div[class] {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or are you just looking for any `div` element?

Then simply use `div`:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe what you need is BolClock's second option :)

Comment: For what it's worth, it's hardly a good idea to `position: relative` a whole big bunch of `div` elements like this. And as far as I know, `div` elements don't have any default margins, borders or padding which need to be zeroed out in any browser.

Comment: i just realized this solution moments ago also all but two of the divs are position: relative by putting this at the top of the stylesheet i can override it later

Comment: just realized you can do this for anything so long as in the classes where it is otherwise you specify it for that class i.e.

    div {height:auto;}
    div.class42 {height: 96px;} the last stated value will be applied